# How to Fix Missing App Icon in WatchOS Dock/App Switcher

Tags: swift, xcode, icons, watchos, dock

I've searched far and wide but can't seem to find a solution. When building a watchOS companion app in Xcode, the App Icon on watchOS is missing in the dock/app switcher screen on the Apple Watch. I've added all the appropriate PNG image sizes in Assets and the icons are displayed correctly everywhere else such as in Notification Center, Companion Settings, Home Screen, Notifications, etc. The only place the icon is missing and just shows a generic wireframe image is in the dock/app switcher screen on the Apple Watch. I've checked the Xcode build settings and made sure the watchOS target is pointing to the correct App Icon Source. Please help. Thanks.

See Image Examples Below:

[image: Xcode App Icon Asset]

[image: Notification Center Screen]

[image: Dock/App Switcher Screen]

Comment: Can you please provide visual explanation (images)

Comment: Sure. Just added. Please see above. Thanks.

Comment: I checked it, everything seems ok. Did you try to refresh `Xcode`? Force Quit `Xcode` then open it again. If the issue still occurs, restart the whole device (your mac) then try it again. Please notify me is it working after this. Sometimes it happens this to `Xcode`, it happened many times through my experience.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I ended up restoring my project from an earlier version in source control (before I added the watchOS extension). I then cleaned my build folder, reinstalled the earlier build on my iPhone, shutdown Xcode, restarted all devices including my MacBook Pro, iPhone, and Apple Watch. I then re-created the watchOS extension from scratch, added the app icons again, and ran on my iPhone/Apple Watch from Xcode. This appears to have fixed the issue and I can now see my icon in the dock/app switcher on Apple Watch. Thanks again.

Comment: Nice to hear that! Glad I contributed something.

Comment: I had this error on an iOS app right after I added icons to the app project. I restarted Xcode and restarted the iPhone simulator (`Hardware -> Restart`), and built the app again. The iOS App Switcher started showing the correct icon after that.